# Why CFile + CArchive performs better than C I/O stream?

Tags: c++, file, stream, mfc, buffer

I am comparing the performance between MFC classes:

- `CFile` + `CArchive` (uses buffer)

and

- `CStdioFile` (uses buffered I/O stream)

Both use a buffer.

The following is my codes:

```
void TestFun1(CFile& File, BOOL bIsMemFile)
{
    CArchive Archive(&File, CArchive::store);
    CString strLine, strOutput;
    UINT uSize;
    BYTE* lpBuf;

    ULONGLONG uStart, uStop;

    uStart = ::GetTickCount64();

    for (UINT nIndex = 0; nIndex < 500; nIndex ++)
    {
        //  Reset the file to empty
        File.SetLength(0);

        strLine.Format(_T("This is line %u."), nIndex);

        for (UINT j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
            File.Write((LPCTSTR)strLine, strLine.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR));

        File.Flush();
    }

    uStop = ::GetTickCount64();

    CString strMsg;

    strMsg.Format(_T("Total time(TestFun1): %I64u."), uStop - uStart);
    AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
}

void TestFun2(CFile& File, BOOL bIsMemFile)
{
    CArchive Archive(&File, CArchive::store);
    CString strLine, strOutput;
    UINT uSize;
    BYTE* lpBuf;

    ULONGLONG uStart, uStop;

    uStart = ::GetTickCount64();

    for (UINT nIndex = 0; nIndex < 500; nIndex ++)
    {
        //  Reset the file to empty
        File.SetLength(0);

        strLine.Format(_T("This is line %u."), nIndex);

        for (UINT j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
            Archive.WriteString(strLine);

        Archive.Flush();
    }

    uStop = ::GetTickCount64();

    CString strMsg;

    strMsg.Format(_T("Total time(TestFun2): %I64u."), uStop - uStart);
    AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
}

void CTestMemFileDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CFile File;
    CMemFile MemFile;

    if (File.Open(_T("E:\\Temp\\testfile.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone))
    {
        TestFun1(File, FALSE);
        TestFun2(File, FALSE);
        TestFun1(File, FALSE);
        TestFun2(File, FALSE);

        File.Close();
    }
}

void CTestMemFileDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CStdioFile File;
    CMemFile MemFile;

    if (File.Open(_T("E:\\Temp\\testfile.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone))
    {
        int nVal;

        nVal = setvbuf(File.m_pStream, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024768);

        TestFun1(File, FALSE);
        TestFun2(File, FALSE);
        TestFun1(File, FALSE);
        TestFun2(File, FALSE);

        File.Close();
    }
}
```

The results are:

Button1:

```
TestFun1: 18174
TestFun2: 375
TestFun1: 18330
TestFun2: 375
```

Button2:

```
TestFun1: 546
TestFun2: 530
TestFun1: 530
TestFun2: 531
```

Based on my test, CFile + CArchive always takes about 66% time of CStdioFile. I try to increase the buffer to CStdioFile to as large as 1MB, but still get the same result.

Therefore, my question is, since both solutions use buffering, why CStdioFile will always slower than CFile + CArchive?

Comment: Note that your code is not C code — there are too many (more than zero) occurrences of `::` which is never valid in C.  You are presumably using MS Visual Studio with MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) — that is C++ code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes, mine is C++ code.

Comment: Code sample could be improved, too much unused code there, which is confusing. In TestFun1, `CArchive` object and other local variables are unused. `CMemFile` object is also unused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CStdioFile` opens files in text mode by default.  This causes translations of special characters such as carriage returns and line feeds, something that obviously is going to take time.

If you want to avoid that, you can add `CFile::typeBinary` to the `nOpenFlags` parameter in the `CStdioFile::open()` call.